# How to fix the "array out of bounds exception"?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```java
public class MDarrays_28 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int flats[][];
        flats = new int[2][3];
        flats[0][0] = 101;
        flats[0][1] = 102;
        flats[0][2] = 103;
        flats[1][0] = 201;
        flats[1][1] = 202;
        flats[1][2] = 203;

        for (int i = 0; i < flats.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < flats[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(flats[i][j]);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

the output:

```
101 102 103 0 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
        at MDarrays_28.main(MDarrays_28.java:15)
```

im very new to computer programming so any help would be really appreciated, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line is wrong:

```
for(int j=0; i<flats[i].length;j++){
```

you should fix it:

```
for(int j=0; j<flats[i].length;j++){
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a for-each loop in this case: it's more efficient and it doesn't give you headaches with variables.

The following should work:

```
for(int[] i : flats){
   for(int j : i){
      System.out.print(j+" ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

[Which prints](https://ideone.com/8Z8kTN):

```
101 102 103 
201 202 203
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the inner for loop, the test condition is incorrect.

Since your iterating variable is `j` (which you are incrementing), your test condition remains constant throughout the execution. Test conditions should be selected in such a way that you evaluate new expressions in every loop.

In your case, the condition should involve variable `j`, as it is the only variable updated in each loop. So, changing the condition in the inner for loop to the following should fix your issue.

```java
for (int j = 0; j < flats[i].length; j++) {
    // ...
}
```